# Write data of two tables in one xml file in MySqlServer

Tags: c#, mysql, xml

I have been trying writing the `MySql` table data in one `XML` file using following code

```
 MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        string CmdString = "SELECT * FROM TBL_USER";
        MySqlCommand cmd;
        MySqlDataAdapter sda;
        DataTable dt;

        using (connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            cmd = new MySqlCommand(CmdString, connection);
            connection.Open();
            dt = new DataTable("Users");
            sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            sda.Fill(dt);
            dt.WriteXml("Users.xml");
            connection.Close();
        }
```

It gives me xml file as

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<DocumentElement>
<Users>
<LNG_USER_ID>9</LNG_USER_ID>
<TXT_NAME>Rajeev </TXT_NAME>
<TXT_MOBILE_NUMBER>9999999</TXT_MOBILE_NUMBER>
<TXT_EMAIL_ID>r@k.com</TXT_EMAIL_ID>
<INT_AGE_GROUP>1</INT_AGE_GROUP>
<TXT_MAC_ADDRESS>C03FD55BD3D8</TXT_MAC_ADDRESS>
<DAT_CREATED>2015-08-07T17:39:12+05:30</DAT_CREATED>
<INT_TRANS_STATUS>0</INT_TRANS_STATUS>
</Users>
</DocumentElement>
```

But i need to write data of another table say `Department` in same `xml` file with different root element. How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

My first though was to join the tables before writing them into xml. But I guess thats not what you need. 
You could write your DataTables into a MemoryStream, then use a combination of XmlReader and XmlWriter to combine those two.